# mDeploy failing after DHF, Gradle and Marklogic upgrades

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf, ml-gradle

We have upgraded MarkLogic (from 10.07 to 11.0.0), Gradle(5.2.1 to 6.4) and DHF(5.2.0 to 5.8.1).
All the upgrades were successful and mlDeploy for 3 out of our 4 code bases also executed successfully.

But, mlDeploy for one code base is failing with the following errors while it is executing without any errors in environments where upgrades have not been done yet:

Gradle error:

```
> Task :mlDeployApp FAILED
:mlDeployApp (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 3 mins 16.45 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mlDeployApp'.
> Error occurred while loading REST modules: Error occurred while loading modules; host: localhost; port: 8011; cause: Local message: config/resources write failed: Bad Request. Server Message: RESTAPI-INVALIDCONTENT: (err:FOER0000) Invalid content: invalid assemblySegmentation extension: could not parse JavaScript extension assemblySegmentation; please see the server error log for detail JS-JAVASCRIPT: ┬á ┬á const bdsQuery = cts.andQuery([ -- Error running JavaScript request: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier; assemblySegmentation either is not a valid JavaScript module or does not export functions (delete, get, put, post)
```

MarklLogic error log:

```
2023-11-06 12:45:52.180 Notice:+  $body = document{text{"const segmentation = require('/custom-modules/segmentationLib..."}}
2023-11-06 12:45:52.777 Info: Status 500: RESTAPI-INVALIDCONTENT: (err:FOER0000) Invalid content: invalid assemblySegmentation extension: could not parse JavaScript extension assemblySegmentation; please see the server error log for detail JS-JAVASCRIPT: Â  Â  const bdsDocument = fn.head(cts.search(bdsQuery)); //bdsPublished Document -- Error running JavaScript request: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier; assemblySegmentation either is not a valid JavaScript module or does not export functions (delete, get, put, post)
2023-11-06 12:45:53.320 Info: <error:error xsi:schemaLocation="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/error error.xsd" xmlns:error="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/error" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
2023-11-06 12:45:53.320 Info:+  <error:code>JS-JAVASCRIPT</error:code>
2023-11-06 12:45:53.320 Info:+  <error:name/>
2023-11-06 12:45:53.320 Info:+  <error:xquery-version>javascript</error:xquery-version>
2023-11-06 12:45:53.320 Info:+  <error:message>Error running JavaScript request</error:message>
2023-11-06 12:45:53.320 Info:+  <error:format-string>JS-JAVASCRIPT: Â  Â  const bdsDocument = fn.head(cts.search(bdsQuery)); //bdsPublished Document -- Error running JavaScript request: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier</error:format-string>
2023-11-06 12:45:53.320 Info:+  <error:retryable>false</error:retryable>
2023-11-06 12:45:53.320 Info:+  <error:expr>Â  Â  const bdsDocument = fn.head(cts.search(bdsQuery)); //bdsPublished Document</error:expr>
2023-11-06 12:45:53.320 Info:+  <error:data>
2023-11-06 12:45:53.320 Info:+    <error:datum>SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier</error:datum>
2023-11-06 12:45:53.320 Info:+  </error:data>
2023-11-06 12:45:53.320 Info:+  <error:stack>
2023-11-06 12:45:53.320 Info:+    <error:frame>
2023-11-06 12:45:53.320 Info:+      <error:uri>/custom-modules/kcqty-lib/pbsEffLib.sjs</error:uri>
2023-11-06 12:45:53.320 Info:+      <error:line>525</error:line>
2023-11-06 12:45:53.320 Info:+      <error:column>7</error:column>
2023-11-06 12:45:53.320 Info:+      <error:xquery-version>javascript</error:xquery-version>
2023-11-06 12:45:53.320 Info:+    </error:frame>
2023-11-06 12:45:53.320 Info:+    <error:frame>
2023-11-06 12:45:53.320 Info:+      <error:uri>[anonymous]</error:uri>
2023-11-06 12:45:53.320 Info:+      <error:line>1</error:line>
2023-11-06 12:45:53.320 Info:+      <error:column>0</error:column>
2023-11-06 12:45:53.320 Info:+      <error:xquery-version>javascript</error:xquery-version>
2023-11-06 12:45:53.320 Info:+    </error:frame>
2023-11-06 12:45:53.320 Info:+    <error:frame>
2023-11-06 12:45:53.320 Info:+      <error:uri>/marklogic.rest.resource/pbsEff/assets/resource.sjs</error:uri>
2023-11-06 12:45:53.320 Info:+      <error:line>2</error:line>
2023-11-06 12:45:53.320 Info:+      <error:column>18</error:column>
2023-11-06 12:45:53.320 Info:+      <error:operation>xdmp:eval("require(&amp;quot;/marklogic.rest.resource/pbsEff/assets/resource.sj...")</error:operation>
2023-11-06 12:45:53.320 Info:+      <error:xquery-version>javascript</error:xquery-version>
2023-11-06 12:45:53.320 Info:+    </error:frame>
```

What could be the reason? Do we need to make any changes to the "sjs"?

Comment: It's telling you there is a syntax error in your assemblySegmentation module. If you want help finding what is wrong with it, then it would be helpful if you could edit the question and post the code from that module.

Comment: But, then how come it is getting deployed successfully on MarkLogic 10.07 + Gradle 5.2.1 + DHF 5.2.0

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your code. Those ` Â  Â  ` before the `const bdsDocument` in the error message look suspicious though. And would explain why you are getting "Unexpected Identifier". https://runjs.app/blog/how-to-solve-unexpected-identifier-error May indicate character encoding issues when reading/writing.

Comment: I have modified the question and added the code snippet where the error is being thrown.

Comment: I suspect encoding issues mangling characters https://github.com/marklogic/ml-gradle/wiki/Encoding-issues

Comment: Big thanks, @MadsHansen! Your solution worked like a charm, and I really appreciate it. You're the boss!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some odd looking characters in the error message:

> JS-JAVASCRIPT: ┬á ┬á const bdsQuery = cts.andQuery([ -- Error running JavaScript request: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier;

If there was a character encoding issue reading/writing the module, then that can cause JavaScript "Unexpected Identifier" exceptions. https://runjs.app/blog/how-to-solve-unexpected-identifier-error

Refer to this ml-gradle wiki page for ways of explicitly setting the character encoding to avoid character encoding issues that cause multi-byte characters to be read incorrectly: https://github.com/marklogic/ml-gradle/wiki/Encoding-issues